# bash - Remove non-UDP related data from pcap file

Tags: bash, networking, wireshark, tcpdump

I have a file called test1.pcap which contains ICMP, ARP, and UDP messages. I want to read test1.pcap and write to test2.pcap with only UDP messages.

I tried the following:

```
tcpdump -r test1.pcap udp -w test2.pcap
```

but the non udp messages - ICMP and ARP still show up in test2.pcap. I used wireshark to view the results.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You _can_ filter just on UDP in Wireshark.

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux. SuperUser.com or unix.stackexchange.com would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: This question has absolutely nothing to do with `bash`. You use `tcpdump` the same way with any shell, or even without a shell at all.